# What kind of sources can integrate CKAN?

Tags: ckan

I would like to use CKAN in my company but firts I have some questions to solve yet. For example:

What kind of sources can integrate CKAN? I explain myself firts.

If my company has its data distributed in the following sources:

- Relational database (mysql, oracle)
- Non relational database (solr, cassandra, mongodb)
- Cloud (amazon s3, dropbox, google drive, google cloud storage)

Can CKAN access to this data sources for separate using a driver o some plugins and upload the data directly for example?

Can CKAN mix these data resources as a mashup tool?

Comment: [*If your question is not closely related to programming, please consider asking your question on https://opendata.stackexchange.com*](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ckan/info)

Comment: Plugins in CKAN can be programmed by the users and maybe this can be the solution.

Comment: In my opinion, "closely related to programming" would be "I'm writing this plugin and it's giving me this error". Asking about what features are available and what plugins can do feels more on the other side.

Comment: ok! i'll try it there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on opendata.stackexchange.com.